# JQuery to Mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

Can anybody help me converting this jquery code into mootools, please?

```
$("#" + '<%= txtInput.ClientID %>').parent().find(".textboxlist-bit-box-deletebutton").each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: You got a nice answer here, you can click to accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.id('<%= txtInput.ClientID %>')
    .getParent()
    .getElements(".textboxlist-bit-box-deletebutton")
    .each(function(button) {
         button.fireEvent("click");
    });
```

Trivially converted from reading the [MooTools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core)

Comment: what is `document.el` then? `document.id("<%=txtInput.ClientID%>").getParent().getElements(".textboxlist-bit-box-deletebutton").fireEvent("click", {stop:Function.from});` - getElements -> performs Slick.find/search, getChildren = direct descendants only. .each is auto performed on the collection as well.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff document.el was a typo. Didn't pay attention to the fact that getChildren doesn't recurse. Thanks!.

Comment: not as if it matters, first question - likely won't know how to accept or what accepting means anyway.